# Dúvida sobre regex

Tags: java, regex

Tenha essa string e preciso percorrer ela pegando só os valores que estão dentro do `()`. 
A *string* é :

```
String estados = “(1, ‘AC', ‘Acre’), (2,’AL', ‘Alagoas’), (3, AM, ‘Amazonas’)… “
```

Montei o seguinte *regex*:

```
Pattern pattern = pattern.compile(“(([^>]*))”);    
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(estados);    
while(matcher.find()){    
  String aux = matcher.group();    
  …    
}
```

Só que ele está retornando o `matcher.group` sempre com valor vazio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esses sinais de aspas estão estranhos, será isto o problema?

Só para resumir o possivel problema deve ser a falta de escape nos parênteses, pois eles são usados para grupos de match, se não escapar ele sempre vai interpretar como agrupador e não como parênteses (deve-se usar o escape duas vezes assim `\\`), fora que o uso do `pattern` parece estar errado (não conheco muito a classe). O regexp também tem um problema, usei a sugestão do @guilhermelautert (`\(([^)]*)\)`)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Exemplo
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String estados = "(1, 'AC', 'Acre'), (2, 'AL', 'Alagoas'), (3, AM, 'Amazonas')";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]*)\\)");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(estados);

        while (matcher.find()) {    
          String aux = matcher.group();
          System.out.println(matcher);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: > illegal escape character in string literal

Comment: @GabrielSouza qual?

Comment: @GabrielSouza editei o exemplo, só precisa corrigir o regex, estou tentando aqui, só um minuto

Comment: Tem problema com essa REGEX, [Original](https://regex101.com/r/QTLpfd/1), [Opção1](https://regex101.com/r/QTLpfd/2), [Opção2](https://regex101.com/r/QTLpfd/3), recomendo a **Opção2**.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert ..  a opções 2 pega os parênteses juntos. Preciso só do que está dentro deles.

Comment: @GabrielSouza [Assim?](https://regex101.com/r/wyYcqy/1) o conteúdo esta no grupo 1.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Perfeito. Muito obrigado.